# Show full details of a column in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget which currently looks like this.

[image: Image here]

May I know how am I supposed to show the full details under the 'anomaly details' column? I want to get rid of the '...' and display the full values under that column. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to set the [textElideMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#textElideMode-prop) to `ElideNone`?

Comment: May I know how do I do that? Thank you

Comment: It's explained in the link of my previous comment: just use `yourTable.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)`.

Comment: I just tried but the results is the same. I found the solution using table.resizeRowsToContents(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, it shouldn't. To show the full contents of a *column* you should be using `resizeColumnsToContents`. So, what's the actual contents of those columns? Is it longer than one line? (For future reference, that's also the kind of info you should provide when asking a question, as your was a bit misleading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourtable.resizeRowsToContents()
```